# Image GD - White Background

Tags: php

```
$background = imagecreatetruecolor(709,709);

$whiteBackground = imagecolorallocate($background, 255, 255, 255);

imagecopyresampled($whiteBackground, $new_img,(709-$imageWidth)/2,(709-$imageHeight)/2, 0, 0, $imageWidth, $imageHeight, $width, $height);

ImageJpeg ($background,"$path/$newName.$file_ext", 85);
```

Im trying to create an image with GD, witha white background. But no luck, any ideas what im doing wrong? I know an mage pumps out ifI take out the whiteBackground bit, so its nothing wrong with the create image code.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are missing `imagefill()` method on `$background` with the allocated white color.

and you can't imagecopyresampled from [color] to [image], you should do it from [image] to [image].

```
$background = imagecreatetruecolor(709,709);
$whiteBackground = imagecolorallocate($background, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($background,0,0,$whiteBackground);
imagecopyresampled($background, $new_img,(709-$imageWidth)/2,(709-$imageHeight)/2, 0, 0, $imageWidth, $imageHeight, $width, $height);
ImageJpeg ($background,"$path/$newName.$file_ext", 85);
```

Answer (score 0):

*I hope this works*

```
$background = imagecreatetruecolor(709,709);
$whiteBackground = imagecolorallocate($background, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($background,0,0,$whiteBackground);
$use_new_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($new_img);
imagecopyresampled($whiteBackground,$use_new_img,(709-$imageWidth)/2,  (709-$imageHeight)/2, 0, 0,$imageWidth,$imageHeight,$width,$height);
ImageJpeg ($background,"$path/$newName.$file_ext", 85);
```

Answer (score -1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php states you that the first two arguments need to be `$dst_image` and `$src_image`.

`$new_img` doesn't exist in your code and needs to be created with `imagecreatetruecolor();`

By default it should be a white background I believe, so you shouldn't need `imagecolorallocate()`